# When using "npm run watch" the webpack get compiled with 2 erros and 6 warnings

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, compiler-errors, npm-run

I'm trying to use Laravel CMS for my portfolio when using the exact same repo on my mac I get no errors or warnings, but when I try using it on my Windows PC I get 6 warning and 2 errors. I'm a beginner level developer, so I don't really know how to read those warnings/errors.

Edit 1:
I forgot to mention that the path i used at first was `public/images/<image.png>` and the same error occured.

Aplication version's:
Php: 8.1.5
Laravel: 9.11.0
npm: 8.5.5

Here is the error snippet:

```
npm  run watch

> watch    
> mix watch
Error: Can't resolve '../../storage/app/resources/images/achtergrond.png' in 'C:\portfolio\resources\css'     
    at finishWithoutResolve (C:\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:309:18)
    at C:\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:386:15
    at C:\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:435:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1
)
    at C:\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:435:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1
)
    at C:\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\DescriptionFilePlugin.js:87:43
    at C:\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:435:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1
)
    at C:\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:435:5
    at processResult (C:\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:758:19)
    at C:\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:860:5
    at C:\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:400:11
    at C:\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:252:18
    at context.callback (C:\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
    at Object.loader (C:\node_modules\css-loader\dist\index.js:155:5)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
webpack compiled with 2 errors and 6 warnings
```

If you need any more information just send me a message.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `../../storage/app/resources/images` does not look like a path that would typically be committed to a repo so check to make sure the same files are there.  I suggest you move those files under `<root path>/resources/<anywhere>`

Comment: Tried it and still didnt help. i forgot to mention in the post (i will edit it in a couple minutes) first path that i used was `public/images/<image.png>` and i had the exact same problem